# Yii2 Error: yii\base\UnknownMethodException: Calling unknown method: yii\web\UrlManager::addRules()

Tags: composer-php, yii2

After todays update of composer dependencies (with composer update command) my Yii2 application became broken - It throws **Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException: Calling unknown method: yii\web\UrlManager::addRules()**

After inspecting *vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/UrlManager.php* file I found that there is no method addRule.
And the whole entire class *UrlManager* is different from the class in the repository.

My composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "2.0.0-beta",
    "claudejanz/yii2-mygii": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "dev-master",
    "2amigos/yii2-switch-widget": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "*",
    "DsXack/yii2-underscore": "*",
    "2amigos/yii2-editable-widget": "*",
    "warrence/yii2-kartikgii": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*"
},
```

Comment: I ran about exactely the same problem after calling "composer update" after adding kartik-v widgets to the require section. still trying to figure out what happened :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5060#issuecomment-55920352) is an explaination of why this happened:

> I think this is again the composer dependency resolver doing unexpected things:
>
> - you require `yiisoft/yii2` in your composer.json but do not have the composer asset plugin installed.
> - then the dependency resolver does not find packages with vendor `bower-asset` so it looks for other versions of `yiisoft/yii2` that do not have conflict
> - The result is to install the beta version of yii2 to be installed

The correct solution as already mentioned is to install the [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin#npmbower-dependency-manager-for-composer):

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"
```

Answer (score 13):

I think they have changed the way some libraries are loaded through composer.

To solve it:

Add to composer.json

```
 "extra": {
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
```

and run:

```
# php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"
# php composer.phar update --dev
```

More info: [Issue on Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5060) and [Issue on Github](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5059)

Full credit to: @githubjeka and @SonicGD

Comment: +1 for sure. i haven't found it on the Github Issues before :(

Comment: i have done this but my issue still not resolved still saying error for csrf meta tag

Answer (score 1):

It seems the update went totally wrong, since the files are different from the ones on github - several functions missing.

What i had to do to get "rid" of this error:

Copy the code from the repository in your local files:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/UrlManager.php

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yiisoft/yii2/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php

This solved it for the moment for me.

Comment: Thanks, I hope they fix it

Comment: Hope it too.. but they say in the docs.. don't use on production... now we know why :D

Comment: even if copying the files from github solves the issue, the correct solution is to install the composer-asset-plugin. So please mark one of the answers suggesting the installation of the plugin as the solution and not this one.

Answer (score 1):

Like ricardgf says, read this:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md

then run:

`composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"`

and

`composer.phar update --prefer-source --no-interaction`

Answer (score 1):

ok I solved the problem installing yii2 in this way :

composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.*@dev"

composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic

Answer (score -4):

Try to update your composer.json into following way:

```
"require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*"
},
```

in project directory, write this command-

```
php composer.phar update
```

Comment: ok i figured it out
there is no addRules($rules, $append = true) function in your yiisoft/yii2/web/UrlManager.php. Strange!!