# Strange Behavior From Composer Again

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php, bower, yii2

I encouraged the same difficulties as described: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57532-streng-behavior-from-composer/

I followed all tips, but now I can't overcome that:

```
[Composer\DependencyResolver\SolverProblemsException]                                              
Problem 1
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap[dev-master].
- yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap dev-master requires bower-asset/bootstrap 3.2.* -> no matching package found.
Problem 2
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[dev-master].
- yiisoft/yii2 dev-master requires bower-asset/jquery 1.11.* | 2.1.* -> no matching package f
ound.
Problem 3
- yiisoft/yii2 dev-master requires bower-asset/jquery 1.11.* | 2.1.* -> no matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2-debug dev-master requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[dev-master].
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-debug * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-debug[dev-master].
Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability seting see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

My composer file:

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "vova07/yii2-rbac-module": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "dev-master",
    "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget" : "*",
    "nex/yii2-chosen": "dev-master",
    "filsh/yii2-flags": "dev-master",
    "zelenin/yii2-summernote-widget": "0.0.1",
    "2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget": "0.1.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-helpers": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-builder": "dev-master",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-dropdown-x": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-nav-x": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "dev-master",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "3.2.*"

},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*"
},
```

I've tried to "bower-asset/bootstrap": "*" with or without this (and other packages). Nothing worked.

Comment: same problem with mee to the is a duplicate issue. 
Issue Started here 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5060
And on git hub
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884038/yii2-error-yii-base-unknownmethodexception-calling-unknown-method-yii-web-url

for me No solution found

Comment: You must have downloaded the latest development version of Yii. Was that on intention? If not then use `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic` to install the stable version.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5107#issuecomment-56160214

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your composer.json

```
...
"Require": {
    ...
    "bower-asset/jquery": "@stable",
    "bower-asset/jquery.inputmask": "@stable",
    "bower-asset/punycode": "@stable",
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "@stable",
    ...
}
```

if you do not have anything after the last one, make sure to remove the comma

Answer (score -1):

delete all data in ./vendor folder and run again: composer update